# get the data from an api with an api key (angular js)

Tags: angularjs

How do we do it in angular js where in we can pull the data from an api
using http request that has api key? i have my code below but the result is empty. Thanks (bow)
Key = 0bc941e9ac52456581855b5edf9abd14
Api =https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=0bc941e9ac52456581855b5edf9abd14

Controller

```
function AppController($scope, TestFac) {
    /* console.log("AppController is now available.");*/
    $scope.data = [];
    TestFac.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;

          console.log("Data:",$scope.data);
    })
}
```

Service(Factory)

```
function TestFac($http) {

return {
  getData: getData
};

function getData() {
  return $http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=0bc941e9ac52456581855b5edf9abd14').then(function(response) {
    return response;
  }, function(error) {
    return error;
  });
}
```

};

Comment: What is the error you are getting? can you add more details as to what you are observing?

Comment: There is no error in the code , it just lack of a logic or a function that would recognized the key and will tap the key on the link &apiKey=key

Comment: It seems you are looking for how to set key dynamically in the request?

Comment: So you dont know where the apiKey is coming from? If you know the value of the key, you can keep it in some configuration file, import it and use it. Best way is to keep it in the environment variable and then access in the code.

Comment: key: string;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http=http;
    console.log('Newsservice Provider');
    this.key = '0bc941e9ac52456581855b5edf9abd14';
  }

 this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en&apiKey=' + this.key)     like this but in angular js expression